# Hover Points inside an responsive image

Tags: css, image, hover

first of all I am not the big front end developer, but I know at least normal CSS design methods. My problem is, I want one image, lets say a worldmap.
On the map I want pins and when someone hovers over that pin a info box will be shown. Thats no problem, when I use CSS circles with a hover effect and a little bit of Javascript. The problem is that the trick with the position of the circles only works, if the size of the image stays the same. When I have a responsive image, the pins are somewhere else.

Thanks!

Comment: scale the image always mantaining its original ratio and use % units for top/left properties to place the pins

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Does this help though - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha